# Google App Engine gcloud alpha source captures upload throws file size warnings

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Using Python 2.7 Django 1.9.latest on Google App Engine, trying to debug in Cloud Debugger. When I run this cmdline to upload code to the debugger:

```
gcloud alpha source captures upload --capture-id <id is here> --project <project id is here> <local source path is here>
```

I get a bunch of errors on the Google Cloud SDK:

```
WARNING: Could not write file "y/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/lib/googlecloudsdk/third_party/apis/compute_alpha.json" because it was too large (839578 bytes). Max size is 262144 bytes
WARNING: Could not write file "y/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/lib/googlecloudsdk/third_party/apis/compute_beta.json" because it was too large (713478 bytes). Max size is 262144 bytes
WARNING: Could not write file "y/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/lib/googlecloudsdk/third_party/apis/compute_v1.json" because it was too large (594590 bytes). Max size is 262144 bytes
```

etc.

GAE SDK is listed as an External Library in my Pycharm project, and it's not explicitly included anywhere in my code's modules.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a "y" directory that keeps a copy of appengine SDK. You might want to add this directory into .gitignore file.

You can probably ignore those. The Cloud Debugger only cares about source files (.py), so not having .json files won't affect it.